# How to redefine a wx.GridSizer?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have this code:

```
class SoundLog(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, size=(500, 350), *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour((110,110,110))
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        pluginsNumber = len(plugins) - len(pluginsToHide)

        self.gs = wx.GridSizer(pluginsNumber, 1, 0, 0)
        pluginsList = self.getPluginsList()
        self.gs.AddMany(pluginsList)
        self.sizer.Add(self.gs, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)
```

How can I make a function that redefines the GridSizer defined here?

Is something like this:

```
def redefineSizer(self):
    self.Show(False)
    pluginsNumber = len(plugins) - len(pluginsToHide)
    self.gs.Clear()
    self.sizer.Remove(self.gs)
    self.gs = wx.GridSizer(pluginsNumber, 1, 0, 0)
    print self.gs
    pluginsList = self.getPluginsList()
    self.gs.AddMany(pluginsList)
    self.sizer.Add(self.gs, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
    self.Centre()
    self.Show(True)
```

or something like this:

```
def redefineSizer(self):
     pluginsNumber = len(plugins) - len(pluginsToHide)
     self.gs.SetRows(pluginsNumber)
     self.gs.Clear(deleteWindows=False)
     pluginsList = self.getPluginsList()
     self.gs.AddMany(pluginsList)
     self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
```

But I know (cause it's not working) that I'm missing something.
What it is?

I put panels inside the GridSizer, but with an option to close them.
When I close one panel, I want to redefine the GridSizer to have one row less and to remove the closed panel.

So, when I click on close, I call redefineSizer to remove that panel and update itself.
That's what I want to do!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: may be instead of givingm solution if you tell what exactly you are trying to achieve, it will be more helpful to understand question

Comment: I put panels inside the GridSizer, but with an option to close them.
When I close one panel, I want to redefine the GridSizer to have one row less and to remove the closed panel.

So, when I click on close, I call redefineSizer to remove that panel and update itself.
That's what I want to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using something like the [AUI framework](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.aui-module.html), you can simply create a new grid sizer, and swap out the one you've already got.